# Работа в PyCharm с Docker

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, pycharm

У меня есть PyCharm CE и Docker контейнер с интерпретатором python и БД. Лежат они на одном уровне. Операционная система - Kubuntu. Как мне указать PyCharm путь к интерпретатору в контейнере? Потому что сейчас он его не видит и не индексирует установленные в этот контейнер библиотеки.

Answer (score 0):

Могу ошибаться, но в докер контейнере открываешь порт. Потом цепляешься через удаленную отладку PyCharm (там есть для этого интерфейс), и все должно работать.

Comment: PyCharm CE не поддерживает удаленную отладку. Btw в Pro версии есть нативная поддержка Docker.